# jQuery Resizable: getting ui-resizable-w to act like ui-resizable-e

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

```
$('#foo').resizable({
   resize:function(){}
});
```

#### Question

1. This creates a east/south handle, how do you create a east/west?
2. By changing the south class (ui-resizable-s) to the west class (ui-resizable-w) -current debug workaround-, the west does not behave like the east.  When the east is dragged, the element is expanded.  When the west is dragged, the element is expanded but a left positioning is also applied.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the manual :](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#option-handles)

> handles
>
> Type:
>       String, Object Default:
>       'e, s, se'
>
> If specified as a string, should be a
>   comma-split list of any of the
>   following: 'n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw,
>   nw, all'. The necessary handles will
>   be auto-generated by the plugin.
>
> If specified as an object, the
>   following keys are supported: { n, e,
>   s, w, ne, se, sw, nw }. The value of
>   any specified should be a jQuery
>   selector matching the child element of
>   the resizable to use as that handle.
>   If the handle is not a child of the
>   resizable, you can pass in the
>   DOMElement or a valid jQuery object
>   directly. Code examples
>
> Initialize a resizable with the
>   handles option specified.
>
> ```
> $( ".selector" ).resizable({ handles: 'n, e, s, w' });
> ```

Comment: +1, I looked at the manual, but must have missed this, thank you.  Now I have to test the 'w' behavior, because I don't want it to set the `left` position in addition to the width.

Comment: Yep, still no good, any ideas on how to turn off the left positioning?  I'm probably missing it in the options, and I hope not to add a callback.

Comment: @vol7ron : I don't really understand your problem with the left positioning you want (or not :S) . Is this solving your issue : http://www.jsfiddle.net/bADLt/1/ ?

Comment: @Chouchenos: the `ui.position.left = ui.originalPosition.left;` is exactly what I needed.  You can see what was happening [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/bADLt/2/) - notice that the right side works, but the left side doesn't.

Comment: @vol7ron : yeah, I supposed it was that but I wasn't sure. Glad you got it right now :)

Comment: The only follow-up I have is, how would you increase the width by 2?  When it's centered like that, it's expanding correctly, but it looks like it's only moving half because it is centered.  I can open a new question if you want :)

Comment: I opened up the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186977/jquery-resizable-doubling-the-resize-width)